# I could not find problem in my laravel code. but it is not working. (localization)

Tags: laravel

this is in app directory

```
'locale' => 'en',
```

this is in web.php

```
Route::get('/{locale?}',function($locale=null){
   
    return view('index');
});

Route::get('/about/{lang?}',function($lang=null){
    App::setlocale($lang);
    return view('about');
});
Route::get('/contact/{lang?}',function($lang=null){
    App::setlocale($lang);
    return view('contact');
});
// Route::get('/portfolio/{lang?}',function($lang=null){
//     App::setlocale($lang);
//     return view('portfolio');
// });
```

[I have commented out the portfolio route but it is still working. if i delete this rout it still works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wW6PP.png)

My app's default language is English. but when I setlocale to en or bn images are not showing correctly.{except index route}
[http://127.0.0.1:8000/about    view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jI5u.png)
[http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/en     view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YQ3S.png)

Comment: can you share your code to display the image?

Comment: Rifat, the problem is on your blade images src. How do you put images on your blade? Share some code, so we could help. Know more about absolute path and relative path https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Comment: <img src="images/illustrations/leaf-bg-top.png" alt="illustrations" class="bg-shape-1 w-100"> Images are in public folder

Comment: Rifat, change your code, give a slash (**/**) before the path, all your images,  like this `<img src="/images/illustrations/leaf-bg-top.png" alt="illustrations" class="bg-shape-1 w-100">` then it will call from your directory root

Comment: Thank you so much. images are working now. but still having a problem. email is not sending when I setlocale to en or bn. it shows. The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD. but  it works fine when I do no declare any language.

Comment: I think you are using `form` to call the route with `POST` method, that's why you geeting this error. Set it to `GET`, or remove the `form` and use anchor tag

Comment: Hey, @sta, considering adding your comment about the slash so that OP can mark it as the solution for the original question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file path describes the location of a file in a web site's folder structure.

```
<img src="images/illustrations/leaf-bg-top.png" alt="illustrations">
```

That means the *"images/illustrations/leaf-bg-top.png"* file is located in the same folder as the current page. 
 If you give a slash (**/**) before the path, :

```
<img src="/images/illustrations/leaf-bg-top.png" alt="illustrations">
```

That means, *images/illustrations/leaf-bg-top.png* file is located in the images folder at the **root** of the current web

Comment: Hmm i have gotten the anwser